# Nokia X with Titanium and GCM?

Tags: titanium, google-cloud-messaging, nokiax

I have a Titanium app working on Android with Google Cloud Messaging, and we've been asked to port it to Nokia X. All the Nokia Notifications documentation I can see just says how easy it is change from GCM to NN, but I can't find anything that clarifies...

A) Does getting the device token works in Titanium? I'm not using the Appcelerator cloud service for push but a plugin to get the GCM device token, presumably as all the APIs match this plugin should [*hopefully*] continue to work?

B) Is moving to NN is required? I don't see any benefit to moving, so is it possible to do nothing and continue to use GCM?

Comment: Gcm does not work on NokiaX , and Nokia Notifications do not work on Non-Nokia devices.. Would that clarify the usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) If you leave the implementation for the GCM there and work as suggested in OneAPK docuemntation, the original API should continue working just fine in environments it was working previously. The Nokia Notification API does not work with other than Nokia X devices, thus it can not be used there though.

b) It is required, the GCM doe not work on Nokia X devices, thus in order to get the notifications functionality, you would be required to use the API which is supported, i.e. the Nokia Notifications API.

Do check the documentations provided in nokia developer site for tasks needed for the porting effords.